# Save array to textarea in order to use it on the next page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textarea containing some html code, the html code being added to a div on page load :

```
var database = $('textarea').val()
$('#output').html(database)
```

Then, I modify the #output, add lots of elements via jquery, and when I save the page, the html is saved to the textarea to be loaded again on the next page load :

```
$('textarea').val($('#output').html())
```

It works, it saves me some lines of code, but it's of course not ideal; apart from the lack of flexibility, the main problem is the weight of the html code saved in the textarea, which could easily go to several mb in a few months.

I want to save as little as possible in the textarea, only the content, and then generate the html on pageload. I'm sure there are better ways to proceed, especially since my html will always have the same structure. So what I did is I put the content in a multidimensional array (or object, I'm not sure of the correct term). All good, but I don't manage to save the result in the textarea. I read about JSON.stringify but didn't manage to use it either.

Here is an example of html and the JS and my last unsuccessful attempt : https://jsfiddle.net/zh6go80q/4/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood why do you want to save it into the textarea but :
I checked the jsfiddle your linked and there are (in my opinion) a lot of of mistakes you could correct :

1. Replace all these divs with [tables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)
2. Use vanilla JS !!!! jQuery is really not needed
3. Learn about [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) in JS, it's really necessary that you learn about it in order to understand other concepts

After learning about objects, try to think on how to save your elements like this :

```
{
    0:{
        team: "My team",
        name: "My name",
        surname: "My surname",
        age: "My age"
    },
    1:{
        team: "My team",
        name: "My name",
        surname: "My surname",
        age: "My age"
    }
    // etc.
}
```

On this you should apply the [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method you mentioned in your message
Now it's your turn to try and learn how to do this in a simple way (Please use vanilla JS and quit jQuery )

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for your reply. 
- What are the advantages of tables above divs ? I see inconvenients (especially if i want my output to be responsive). The example i pasted is an example to show the basic structure, not my actual html.
- Yeah, i might learn vanilla JS, but for now i need is results quick and what I know is jquery (i'm not a pro dev) - I will look further into objects, thanks.

Comment: `<table>`s are non-responsive.  Resize OPs fiddle to a very narrow window as an example.  Tables should be used for tabular data only, not for layout - though it's hard to tell from the fiddle if this fits, it looks like it does, but it's not a *general* "use tables" as appears to be advocated here.

Comment: Otherwise, this answer is correct:  create an object and stringify the results.  Here's your fiddle with the *array* stringified, though would be better as an object:  https://jsfiddle.net/ynvf4gwc/

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to be mean or mocking in any way, I'll be careful next time. Thanks for the advice!